# Best solution for optional parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

Consider following sample procedure that take some parameters.

```
Create Procedure CustomerSearch(
@Name       nVarChar(100) = Null,
@Phone      nVarChar(100) = Null,
@Address    nVarChar(100) = Null,
)
As

Select  *
        From    dbo.CustomerView
        Where   (@Name      is Null or Name     =   @Name)  And
                (@Phone     is Null or Phone    =   @Phone) And
                (@Address   is Null or Address  =   @Address)
```

Because value of parameters might be null, I find tow solutions for handle it.

1. Use or contition like this:
   (@Name      is Null or Name     =   @Name)
2. Use dynamic sql and add condition to query if parameter value is not null.

Exists several table join in CustomerView view and this table have large amount of data and performance is very important. Solution 1 has overhead (execution plan). For some reasons I can not use Dynamic sql. There is a better way to build this query?

When I use condition @Name is Null or Name = @Name) instead of Name = @Name and view execution plan, index seek cost increases.

Comment: You might find this resource useful: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, for your case I would wrap the parameters in a NULLIF(@Parameter,'') to prevent blanks from being compared.

Here's another way of writing your query as well. If the parameter is blank or null, it'll compare the column to itself which is always true.

```
Name = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Name,''),Name)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ff42/1

Answer (score 2):

Your code posted above is perfectly acceptable. If performance is an issue, ensure there are indexes on the Name, Phone, and Address columns.

Comment: I created index on this columns and it not my problem. When I run query it take too much time and when I view execution plan it (check null parameter) take process versus using name = @name condition.

Comment: Can you please provide the indexes created?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`  to the end of your stored procedure.

Whenever a stored procedure is run in SQL Server for the first time, it is optimized and a query plan is compiled and cached in SQL Server's memory.

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

> **RECOMPILE**
>   Instructs the SQL Server Database Engine to discard the plan generated for the query after it executes, forcing the query optimizer to recompile a query plan the next time the same query is executed. Without specifying *RECOMPILE*, the Database Engine caches query plans and reuses them. When compiling query plans, the *RECOMPILE* query hint uses the current values of any local variables in the query and, if the query is inside a stored procedure, the current values passed to any parameters.
>   *RECOMPILE* is a useful alternative to creating a stored procedure that uses the WITH RECOMPILE clause when only a subset of queries inside the stored procedure, instead of the whole stored procedure, must be recompiled. For more information, see Recompile a Stored Procedure. *RECOMPILE* is also useful when you create plan guides.

Comment: Ok. Notice that my problems is index seek cost increases for condition (@Name is Null or Name = @Name) instead of Name = @Name.